# AngularJS Dropdown required validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, angularjs-validation

Following is my code snippet. I want to validate my dropdown using angular.

```
<td align="left" width="52%"> 
  <span class="requiredSmall">*</span> 
    <select class="Sitedropdown" style="width: 220px;" 
            ng-model="selectedSpecimen().serviceID" 
            ng-options="service.ServiceID as service.ServiceName for service in services"> 
         <option value="" ng-selected="selected">Select Service</option> 
   </select> 
</td>
```

Valid means:

*Valid values can be anything but "Select Service", it is my default value. Like other ASP.net Require field validator DefaultValue="0" for dropdown, so here My dropdown will be bound from the services and I want to select all other values except "Select Service".*

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You need to add a `name` attribute to your dropdown list, then you need to add a `required` attribute, and then you can reference the error using `myForm.[input name].$error.required`:

HTML:

```
        <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-submit="save(myForm)" novalidate>
        <input type="text" name="txtServiceName" ng-model="ServiceName" required>
<span ng-show="myForm.txtServiceName.$error.required">Enter Service Name</span>
<br/>
          <select name="service_id" class="Sitedropdown" style="width: 220px;"          
                  ng-model="ServiceID" 
                  ng-options="service.ServiceID as service.ServiceName for service in services"
                  required> 
            <option value="">Select Service</option> 
          </select> 
          <span ng-show="myForm.service_id.$error.required">Select service</span>

        </form>

    Controller:

        function Ctrl($scope) {
          $scope.services = [
            {ServiceID: 1, ServiceName: 'Service1'},
            {ServiceID: 2, ServiceName: 'Service2'},
            {ServiceID: 3, ServiceName: 'Service3'}
          ];

    $scope.save = function(myForm) {
    console.log('Selected Value: '+ myForm.service_id.$modelValue);
    alert('Data Saved! without validate');
    };
        }
```

Here's a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xmycAAkWZI5VOogi1MyQ).

Comment: It should be mentioned that select needs ng-model for this to work

Comment: Correct, ngOptions require ngModel.

Comment: You have used Dirty, but the user who pressed the submit button directly will not see this message. If you set a parameter like showmessage when you submit the form and use this parameter instead of dirty, it works better.

Comment: I am having an issue with this example. I have a submit button. It works for if I change the selected option to something that is non-default, then switching back to default and trying to submit. The error msg properly shows. But, if I come to the screen and immediately click the submit button, no error message is shown even though the default option is...defaultly selected.

Comment: I was able to overcome this by setting the variable I have as the ng-model for the select to null and having the ng-show as (formName.myoption.$dirty || isSubmitted) && formName.myoption.$error.required.  With isSubmitted being set to true when the Submit button is clicked.

Comment: How would one also set myForm.service_id as $invalid for example if ServiceID  < 2? I tried min="2" to no avail. Also, I'm using Angular Materials md-select if that matters.

Comment: Genious - didnt have id/name attribute and validation was not working properly - it prevented form submission, but didn't show error on the field.